# How can I draw multiple images and assign them to players.[html5 canvas]

Tags: html, canvas, socket.io

Hello I want to make that when player connect to the game, client draw image for them every time someone connect and assign somehow it to them that when they move other could see exactly that player image moving.

Here is my code:

when player connect to the server

```
socket.on('connected', function(data)
{
    if(username != data.username)
    {
    newplayer = true;
    newplayername = data.username;
    playerdirection = data.playerdirection;
    playerframe = data.playerframe;
    }
});
```

then client draws image for him:

```
var playerimage = new Image();
playerimage.src = "images/player.png";

if(newplayer == true)
{
ctx.drawImage(playerimage, playerframe, playerdirection, 96/3, 128/4, playerx, playery, 96/3, 128/4);
}
```

I want to make that every player could have it's own image with own playerx and playery because every player have only overall image... (**all players controls one image**)

Comment: Player s emit their own x,y to server. Server broadcast s all player sprite and position x,y